# Error occur while uploading image, file in dspace 7 while creating community and items in dspace 7

Tags: dspace

In dspace7.6 I have downloaded both frontend and backend and connect that locally. When I create community the logo was failed to upload.

```
type here
```

Where will the image was stored, what are the configuration I need to change. I have create n AWS s3 bucket also but not storing.